# req.session.passport and req.user blank , and req.isAuthenticated returns false after initial successful login using passport-facebook

Tags: node.js, authentication, express, passport.js, passport-facebook

After the initial successful login from Facebook  and login redirection callback  using passport-facebook 1.0.3 and express 4.6.1,req.session.passport and req.user contains the value set during the serialize call(which i get from the stragegy) , but on subsequent visits to different routes on the site the req.session.passport and req.user is  blank , and req.isAuthenticated() returns false , so after the initial successful login from FB the ensureAuthentication method on all other routes  fails .
I'm not using a cluster setup , so i believe the memory store is enough to handle this , the express configuration looks fine(i mean the order) , here is my express configuration

```
configExpressApp.set('views',  './views');
configExpressApp.set('view engine', 'jade');
configExpressApp.use(morgan('dev'));
configExpressApp.use(cookieParser());
configExpressApp.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true,
}));
configExpressApp.use(bodyParser.json());
configExpressApp.use(expressSession({
  secret:'MyExpressSecret', 
  saveUninitialized: true,
  resave: true
}));
configExpressApp.use(passport.initialize());
configExpressApp.use(passport.session());
configExpressApp.use(methodOverride());
configExpressApp.use(express.static('./public'));
```

Here is the req.session object on the initial successfull login and redirection ,The req.user contains the same data as the req.session.passport.user

```
{ cookie: 
   { path: '/',
     _expires: null,
     originalMaxAge: null,
     httpOnly: true },
  passport: 
   { user: 
      { _id: 53ce23e3121421f229a438f8,
        info: false,
        loginType: 'fb',
        fbId: 'MyId',
        name: 'Karthic Rao',
        email: 'kartronics85@yahoo.com'

        }
     }
}
```

this is the information i associated earlier with the done() callback inside the strategy and also inside the serialization call . After the successfull login and callback, i use res.redirect to redirect the user to a different route , but the requests coming from that route contains the sessionID (so i dont think its the issue with the session store), but the req.user field doesnt exist(may be because passport.initialize() and passport.session() middlewares dont find the request to be authenticated) and the req.session.passport field is empty , here are the details from the console.log of the req object .

```
sessionID: 'I9R1c3PIYgDW5OpWbNT7qb02Hn4lOeAB',
session: 
   { cookie: 
      { path: '/',
        _expires: null,
        originalMaxAge: null,
        httpOnly: true },
     passport: {} },
```

Here is my deserialize method

```
passport.deserializeUser(function(user, done) {
    console.log('deserialize loginType facebook');
    db.collection("users").findOne({
        fbId: user.id
    }, function(err, docs) {
        console.log(docs);
        done(err, docs);
    });
});
```

Here is my serialize method

```
passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) { 
    console.log(user);
    done(null, user);
});
```

This is creating a great hindrance to my development , how can i sort this out ??

Comment: Hmmm... I don't have immediate solutions to suggest you, but could you show us your `serializeUser` and `deserializeUser` methods ?
To me, it looks like whatever's stored in session is not properly deserialized.

Comment: i have edited the question , added my serialize and deserialize methods at the end of the question .Thank you for the reply !

Comment: Ive also noticed that the 'user' object sent to the deserialize method on subsequent request is 'null' !

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, if you could add the code where you use your strategy (it should be in the middleware), that would give us a complete view of the problem, because we need to know what object is sent to `serializeUser`.

(Very) basically, when a user tries to authenticate, things happen that way :

- Passport tries to authenticate your user against Facebook servers
- If it succeeds, the callback function (or successRedirect) is called
  with an object containing the user's details
- Then, Passport makes a call to `req.login` to store some info about
  the user in session
- Then `serializeUser` is called and effectively store the data *you*
  specified in session.

BUT from the code you posted, I suspect that in your `deserializeUser`, **user.id** is undefined, because the `user` object that is stored in session uses an ID field called **_id** and not **id**.

If you change

```
 db.collection("users").findOne({
        fbId: user.id
```

to

```
db.collection("users").findOne({
        fbId: user._id
```

```
db.collection("users").findById(user._id, [fields],[options],[callback]);
```

I think it should work.

**EDIT** : I edited my answer based on @BrandonZacharie's remark, which pointed out an error in my code.

Comment: Shouldn't that be "...findOne({ fbId: user.fbId }..." or "...findOne({ _id: mongodb.ObjectId(user._id) }..." instead?

Comment: @BrandonZacharie I re-read your comment (and deleted my previous one, as it was wrong). I think you are right. I just copy-pasted Karthic Rao's code without paying attention. Mongoose even has a [findById method](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findById) which accepts an "objectid, or a value that can be casted to one" as its first parameter.
I'll edit my answer based on your suggestion if that's ok with you (or you could post your comment as answer).

Comment: Yes the _id filed being referred as id was certainly one of the issue . But the other issue was also that i was using requirejs at the backend to modularize and nodejs codes , i did a mistake of using a different passport object for configuring as middlewares (passport.session() and passport.initialize() ) and i had called serializeUser and deserializeUser on  a different passport object . Its working now , thank you for all your efforts in helping me out !

Comment: Hello there, i got similar problem yet it seems that my implementation is rightm as session.passport is containing serialised  data after authenticate call, but not on any further calls, if you have some spare time can you look at my question here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29233791/passport-js-session-passport-empty-on-calls-after-authenticate