# Passport.js `isAuthenticated()` inconsistent behavior; false when it should be true

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

I'm using Passport to allow user logins through Google. The session is being stored in Postgres. It looks to me like I've got all of those things configured correctly. However, `isAuthenticated()` is returning inconsistent values.

The inconsistency happens in the success callback of being authenticated. I've configured passport to redirect to `/success` when the user has successfully logged in.

If the server has just been booted up (meaning nobody has tried logging in yet), then `isAuthenticated()` returns `true` for the `/success` endpoint.

Once that user logs out, though, if they log back in, then `isAuthenticated()` returns `false` on the `/success` route. If they refresh the page, then it returns `true`.

The `/logout` endpoint is also acting inconsistently. Sometimes it works the first time, while at other times the user needs to refresh.

I've looked at similar problems folks are having. In particular, the two most common problems seem to not be the case here:

1. CORS is set ([SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29237690/1727181) / [my code](https://github.com/jmeas/finance-app/blob/google-sign-in/server/app.js#L40))
2. the order of my middleware seems to be correct ([SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21366070/1727181) / [my code](https://github.com/jmeas/finance-app/blob/google-sign-in/server/app.js#L42-L58))
3. `logIn` isn't relevant since I'm not putting a custom callback ([SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23355026/1727181))
4. serialize working correctly; it's just not getting called in certain situations ([SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25010773/1727181) / [explanation in here; `session` isn't finding `su`](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/issues/482#issuecomment-216100150))

For the past few hours, I've been stepping through the Passport source code to try to figure this out. More information on what I've found can be read about here [on the Passport repo.](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/issues/482#issuecomment-216100150)

The project that this is going in is open source. The middleware is being configured here:

https://github.com/jmeas/finance-app/blob/google-sign-in/server/app.js

and the Passport configuration can be seen here:

https://github.com/jmeas/finance-app/blob/google-sign-in/server/utils/configure-passport.js

Perhaps I'm missing something obvious?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tl;dr is that you need to manually call save in certain browsers (like Chrome). They won't wait for the whole response before redirecting.

For more, see:

https://github.com/expressjs/session/issues/309#issuecomment-230594298

and linked issues. I walk through everything pretty thoroughly there.

Comment: I recommend you bring the code off of github and paste it in the answer here on stackoverflow. That will reduce the additional click needed to solve this problem.